# Gaierror from python smtplib

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail

This line is throwing a gaierror... any idea why? Could it be a firewall?

```
smtp=smtplib.SMTP(host=EMAIL_HOST,port=EMAIL_PORT)
```

I'm using gmail so the host is 'alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', and the port is 587.

Comment: Could you post the actual error message?  Guessing unable to resolve host, but can you please post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this weren't a gaierror (which, as AJ rightly says is a DNS lookup error), that host doesn't work for me either.

Specifically, it hangs trying to connect and times out.

However, the following seems to work:

```
import smtplib
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
smtp=smtplib.SMTP(host=EMAIL_HOST,port=EMAIL_PORT)
```

Hope that helps.